# JSdoc for file stream

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

I am creating a stream as :-

```
var stream = fs.createWriteStream("filepath");
```

Now, I am passing this as argument to a function. When writing the JSdoc for this method, I am not sure what would be its type. So, can someone tell me what would be its type in JSdoc?

Answer (score 4):

This is kind of a late answer but I recently encountered a similar problem.

The object returned by `fs.createWriteStream` is of type `WriteStream` as described by the [API Reference of Node](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options)

You can use import in jsDoc `@type` as follows.

```
const fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Some definition explaining what this constant is
 * @constant
 * @type {import('fs').WriteStream}
 */
const stream = fs.createWriteStream("filepath");
```

I found about it [here](https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc/issues/1537#issuecomment-457231965).

In my case, I was reusing the `WriteStream` file multiple times so I used a combination of `@typedef` and `@type`

```
/**
 * @typedef {import('fs').WriteStream} WriteStream
 */
const fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Some definition explaining what this constant is
 * @constant
 * @type WriteStream
 */
const stream = fs.createWriteStream("filepath");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think JSDocs has a specific type for this node api. However, you can put the class as type and I think it will be equally valid. According to node documentation the class is `stream.Writable`, so you can use that.
[Node Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable)